# Выпадающий список(тег <select>) некорректно выглядит на скриншоте, сделанном selenium методом get_screenshot_as_file()

Tags: python, selenium, screenshots

Делаю скриншот страницы с открытым выпадающим списком(html тег списка "select").
Для скриншота вызываю selenium метод **driver.get_screenshot_as_file()**.
При выполнении теста визуально все хорошо, однако, на получившемся скриншоте, содержимое выпадающего списка смещается ниже от поля.
В качестве альтернативы пробовал делать скриншот через Python PIL | ImageGrab.grab(). И это работает, но тогда получается снимок всего экрана, а мне нужна только область страницы в браузере.
Хочу получить результат как от get_screenshot_as_file() но с корректным отображением выпадающего списка

[image: скриншот скриншота открытого выпадающего списка]